# Why was my visa identified by the airline as invalid?

Tags: visas, philippines, turkish-airlines

This is a curious case. My tourist visa was issued at the embassy of the Philippines in Tehran, Iran. **My visa was valid until November 29, 2023. That means that I was allowed to enter the Philippines until November 29, 2023, which means that I was allowed to enter the Philippines on the very last day, that is November 29, 2023. Is that correct?**

**I should add that the Philippines tourist visa allows travelers to stay 30 days in the Philippines.** This is the picture of that section of my visa that determines validity.

[image]

So my flight was at 2:00 AM, on November 29, 2023. And the arrival time was the same day at 22:00. I know it was borderline in terms of visa validity, but that was the only flight that I could find suitable for my schedule.

My flight was by Turkish Airlines, from Isfahan to Manila, with a layover in Istanbul.

At the Isfahan airport I was told by Turkish Airlines that my visa “is identified by the system as invalid”. And they even accused me of visa forgery! I thus lost my flight and came back home.

How is such a thing possible? What am I missing here? Is that because I was traveling on the last day of my visa validity? Or is Turkish Airlines responsible for this inconvenience? I have already sent an email to the Philippines embassy. But I would like to get some suggestions here.

Comment: Did they tell you anything more specific about *why* they thought it was forged? We can't really read their minds…

Comment: @deceze: they will not tell you. Else one organization would improve such details until it get the system. (and variability of stamps between embassies will not help reducing false positive)

Comment: @deceze. First they said the system says it is invalid. Then the airline lady scratched some text on my visa (by her nail!) and said it is erased so it is fake!

Comment: @deceze They also said that their system doesn’t recognize the hologram (barcode) on the visa.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150000/discussion-on-question-by-sasan-why-was-my-visa-identified-by-the-airline-as-inv); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.